# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a generated project working correctly and I have added an attribute to a main class.

```
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
```

in the database table I have correctly added the corresponding column but when starting the project
show me the error

```
    GRAVE: Excepción arrancando filtro encodingFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5329)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 35 more
```

I don't understand it either because I have more columns and I had previously added them without problems

Comment: Are you sure that your `main class` is an entity (class annotated by @Entity)?

Comment: Yes, this error did not have it before the main class has many more attributes and

Comment: it might be that the file is corrupt, try to clean the project. If still not working re-download the jar.

Comment: thanks, I have cleaned the server and built the project again and everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

thanks to [Aman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2660789/aman) I have fixed the problem by cleaning the tomcat